# Is it possible to create editable 3D templates in blender?

Tags: animation, export, unity, source-code

I hope someone can help me:

Is it possible to turn animations created in blender into editable 3D templates that can be used in websites or apps where users can edit the scale and add textures etc I’ve seen this done before, I just don’t know how this was done perhaps there are 3rd party platforms such as “unity” that can transfer animations from blender into code to be edited later and added into a mobile app or website

I greatly appreciate any help

Best regards
Aggers

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks